# How to find data by dynamic conditions on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am using Rails 3.2.13 now.

I made this method:

```
def search
  search_conditions = []
  search_conditions << ["id = ?", params[:id]] if params[:id] != ''
  search_conditions << ["name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:name]}%"] if params[:name] != ''
  @users = User.find(:all, :conditions => search_conditions)
end
```

But the result was:

```
undefined method `%' for ["name LIKE ?", "%tes%"]:Array
```

Can't I set multiple conditions in a nice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def search
  re = Outlet.where( 1 ) 
  re = re.where( "id = ?", params[:id] ) if params.has_key? :id
  re = re.where( "name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:name]}%" ) if params.has_key? :name
  # chain it further as required...

  re.all 
end
```

As mentioned by JC Avena earlier, it's better to use the Rails 3 "where(...)" syntax instead of the "find(:all, ... )"

Comment: Thank you for giving a sample. But why shouldn't use `find` but `where` with Rails3? Isn't a lazy-load problem when using `where` in Rails3?

Comment: Basically, "where" returns a relationship instead of result data set. So it is much easier to chain a few "where"s. When you want to use the results, call first or all on the relation. The flexibility of "where" is much higher than the Rails 2's "conditions". And some (or many?) of the methods related to "find" are deprecated. find(:all) will return an error message in Rails 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Rails 3.2, you should switch to using AREL syntax. There are a lot of tutorials out there for it. It makes building these kinds of queries more intuitive and quite simpler. You can chain multiple where statements in your query when you use AREL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a good information. I made this: `users = User.arel_table @users = User.where(users[:id].eq(params[:id].or(users[:name].matches("%#{params[:name]}%"))))`. Now I want to do the search if user choose a condition, so if user set `id` only, the SQL like: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE ((`users`.`id` = 123456789 OR `users`.`name` LIKE '%%'))`. It's not good. I want to separate them.